# Не могу разобраться с получением IP по DNS имени! :(

Tags: ip, c++, сокет, dns, linux

Вот код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int sock;
    struct sockaddr_in addr;

    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sock < 0)
    {
        cout << "Socket ERROR!" << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htons(7771);
    char host1[] = "example.com"; //здесь коректное имя хоста
    struct hostent* hostA = gethostbyname(host1);
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(hostA->h_addr);

    cout << hostA->h_addr << endl; //выводит 2 символа на 2 строки(какая-то кракозябра)
    cout << addr.sin_addr.s_addr << endl; //число (для google.com вышло 4294967295)

    if (connect(sock, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(addr)) < 0)
    {
        cout << "Connect ERROR!" << endl; //тут все заканчивается.
        return 1;
    }

    ...

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
HOSTENT *hosten; 
hosten = gethostbyname( name ); 
sa.sin_addr.s_addr = ((in_addr*)hosten->h_addr_list[0])->s_addr;
```

вот таким образом можна

Comment: Так заработало.
Это потому что hosten->h_addr это in_addr_t а нужен был in_addr->s_addr?

Comment: да, как видишь

Answer (score 1):

Вместо

```
cout << addr.sin_addr.s_addr << endl; //число (для google.com вышло 4294967295)
```

Напишите:

```
cout << inet_ntoa(addr.sin_addr) << endl; //число (для google.com вышло 4294967295)
```

Выводит на экран 255.255.255.255. Что вполне логично. Т.к. 4294967295 - максимальное long int число.

PS: пишем под Linux/Windows или просто переносимо?

PPS: рабочий пример есть на http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms738524(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Пишем под Linux.

Answer (score 1):

```
struct addrinfo hints, *res;
char ipstr[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];

memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints);
hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
if((status = getaddrinfo(argv[1], NULL, &hints, &res)) != NO_ERROR)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(status));
    return 3;
}

for(p = res; p != NULL; p = p->ai_next)
{
    void *addr;
    char *ipver;

    if(p->ai_family == AF_INET)
    {
        struct sockaddr_in *ipv4 = (struct sockaddr_in*)p->ai_addr;
        addr = &(ipv4->sin_addr);
        ipver = "IPv4";
    }
    else
    {
        struct sockaddr_in6 *ipv6 = (struct sockaddr_in6*)p->ai_addr;
        addr = &(ipv6->sin6_addr);
        ipver = "IPv6";
    }

    inet_ntop(p->ai_family, addr, ipstr, sizeof ipstr);
    printf("  %s: %s\n", ipver, ipstr);
}

freeaddrinfo(res);
```

Что-то в этом духе. Работает и на IPv6.

Answer (score 0):

Кусок из реально работающей программы.
Вызов: int sock = Connect("host:port");

Host может быть по имени или по адресу типа 10.1.3.122

Includ-ов на самом деле многовато, наверное для этого куска многие не нужны.

```
#include  <stdio.h>
#include  <stdlib.h>
#include  <string.h>
#include  <sys/types.h>
#include  <sys/time.h>
#include  <unistd.h>
#include  <fcntl.h>
#include  <ctype.h>
#include  <errno.h>
#ifdef WIN32
// gcc ... -lws2_32 -lwsock32
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <windows.h>
#else
#include  <sys/types.h>
#include  <sys/socket.h>
#include  <netinet/in.h>
#include  <netdb.h>
#include  <arpa/inet.h>
#endif

#ifdef WIN32
void
Clean_tcp ()
{
   while (WSACleanup() == 0);
}
#endif

static int cleanup = 0;

int
Connect (char *addr)
{
  char *port, host[100];
  struct sockaddr_in   sin;
  struct hostent       *h;
  short p;
  int   conn;

  if (!cleanup) {
#ifdef WIN32
    WSADATA wsaData;

    WSAStartup (MAKEWORD(2,2),&wsaData);
    atexit (Clean_tcp);
#endif
    cleanup = 1;
  }

  strncpy (host,addr,99);
  host[99] = 0;
  if (!(port = strchr(host,':')))
  return -1;
  *port++ = 0;

  conn = socket ( AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM , 0 );
  if ( conn < 0 ) {
perror("socket");
exit (1);
  }

  memset ((char *)&sin,0,sizeof(sin));
  sin.sin_family      = AF_INET;
  if (!host[0])
sin.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
  else {
if ((sin.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(host)) == -1) {
  errno = 0;
  if (h = gethostbyname(host))
    memcpy((char *)&sin.sin_addr.s_addr,h->h_addr,h->h_length);
  else {
    if (errno)
      perror ("gethostbyname");
    else
      fprintf (stderr,"Unknown host: [%s]\n",host);
  Err:;
    close (conn);
    return -1;
  }
}
  }
  sin.sin_port        = htons ( p = atoi(port) );
  /*
printf ("Ready to connect: %x:%d socket = %d (%s)\n",
sin.sin_addr.s_addr,sin.sin_port,conn,inet_ntoa(sin.sin_addr));
  */
  if (connect(conn,(struct sockaddr *)&sin,sizeof(sin)) < 0)
return -1;
  return conn;
}
```

уСТАЛ ФОРМАТИРОВАТЬ