# Парсинг ip-адреса c++

Tags: c++

После ввода пользователем ip-адреса нужно проверить его на валидность, то есть просто что это действительно ip, а не абракадабра. Как это сделать на c++? и есть ли какие нибудь библиотеки стандартные  для этого?

Comment: Что подразумевается под ip-адресом? Четыре десятичных числа, задающие адрес IPv4? символьный адрес типа `hashcode.ru`?
Что значит "не абракадабра"? (более внятные предположения можно делать после ответа на первый вопрос)

Comment: все эти вопросы вызваны плохим пониманием что такое ip

Comment: Так и ответили бы простыми словами, (хорошо бы со ссылками на rfc). А то понять, что значит для Вас "абракадабра" из вашего вопроса сложно.

Comment: Просто я не думал, что в наше время ещё ктото не знает что такое ip, и ему для этого нужны ссылки на rfc. А "абракадабра" - это всё отличное от обычного ipv4 если кто не догадался.

Comment: Ну недогадлив, каюсь. Было б написано, что нужна `inet_addr` -  так проще было бы. Ну или примеры, хотя бы. А так -- вариантов-то много.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Как проверить char* на соответствие?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/12881/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-char-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B5)

[Не могу разобрать с получинем IP по DNS имени! :(](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/12494/%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%83-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BC-ip-%D0%BF%D0%BE-dns-%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8)

Comment: мне нужна была только функция inet_addr(...), а эти ссылки хоть и не прямо, но всё же отвечают на мой вопрос.